# Twitter Oauth 2.0 (abraham lib.) Как получить данные пользователя?

Tags: callback, oauth, twitter

После авторизации с помощью Twitter REST API оказываюсь на заданной CALL_BACK странице с `$_GET['oauth_token']`, `$_GET['oauth_verifier']` и `$_SESSION['oauth_token']`, `$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']`.

Делаю объект:

```
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
```

Получаю access_token:

```
$access_token = $twitteroauth->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));
```

Здесь в `$access_token->screen_name` содержится регистрационное имя пользователя Twitter.

А как получить остальные данные: Имя, изображение?..

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved: http://coddism.com/php/oauth_avtorizacija_cherez_twitter

Thanks to Ukrainian devs!